# Check if the string contains all the values of an array

Tags: php, arrays, string, search

First, let me explain what I will do with this piece of code. I have a database and a user interface to search the values within. Users are likely to type more than one keyword. So that I need to check if all the values in the array exist in my database.

For instance if they would type **"green apple"** and I had a string value of this kind **"That *green*ish pine*apple* is gross"**, I am supposed the display this search result. On this account I figured out that somehow I need to find a way to check if the string values contain all values in the array, or not.

Thanks a million

Answer (score 0):

If you're not searching through `TEXT`, you can use [MySQL Like](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/pattern-matching.html).

```
CREATE TABLE TableA (
    `text` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY
);

INSERT INTO TableA (`text`) VALUES
('I like green and purple apples'),
('I hate red apples'),
('You like oranges');
```

You'll have to build the string of Likes from the array in PHP. Below I use `PDO`, but you can easily adjust it for `mysqli`.

```
$search_query = "green apples";
$keywords = explode(' ', $search_query);

$where = '1'; /* We use the 1 so we can prepend 'AND' w/o another case. */
foreach ($keywords as &$word) {
    $where .= " AND LIKE ?";
    $word = "%{$word}%";
}

unset($word);

$stmt = $PDO_Connection->prepare("SELECT `text` FROM Table A WHERE {$where}");
if ($stmt->execute([$keywords])){
    while ($row = $stmt->fetch()){
        echo $row['text'] . '<br />';
    }
}
```

If you are searching through text, you can do something similar with [Full Text Search](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/fulltext-search.html)

Answer (score -1):

I guess mysql full text search can help you if you get your array from database.

Comment: Thanks but I am afraid I could not understand how I would use MySQL text search to fix this.

Comment: it is much easier than writing a search ranking algorithm. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-natural-language.html